# How to pin link with parameters to printerest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pinterest

I try to pin the link with multiple parameters, but its take only one parameter. I am using html (JS also fine for me).

Comment: Are you able to supply the code you're using that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Pinterest does not have a public API yet.

[Here](http://tijn.bo.lt/pinterest-api) is a website that discloses some information on the API to be released.